# write a bash renaming script

Tags: shell

I couldn't figure it out, Need help with the following task:

The existing Linux program foo2bar takes as its only argument the name of a single foo file and converts it to an appropriately-named bar file. Provide a script that when executed will run foo2bar against all foo files in the current directory.

Comment: Related question: [Better way to rename files based on multiple patterns](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25597051/2654678).

Answer (score 2):

If I understand right:

```
#!/bin/sh

for f in *.foo; do
  foo2bar "$f"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "for r in `find . -name "*foo*"` ; do mv $r $r"-" ; done" to rename foo files in current directory.

```
 # ls
 1.foo  2.foo  3.foo  foo  foo.1  foo.2  foo.3

 # for r in `find . -name "*foo*"` ; do mv $r $r"-" ; done

 # ls
 1.foo-  2.foo-  3.foo-  foo-  foo.1-  foo.2-  foo.3-
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the [`rename`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?rename+1) command may be your friend here.

i.e.

```
rename foo bar *foo*
```

will change all the `foo` to `bar` for the file names with `foo` in them.